# Cannot find module 'express' on cpanel

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I tried to setup nodejs on a cpanel nodejs app. I put my package.json on my /games folder, and when I do run npm install, the folder node_modules is created but when I launch my app and go to my link (falsegames.com/game), I am getting an error.

I already tried to place my real folder node_modules instead of the one created by cpanel but it still didnt worked. The error is cannot find module express but it is in my package.json file.

[image: JSON screenshot]

My server.js:

```
const game = require("./board");


const express = require('express');
const util = require('util');
let app = express();
//var http = require('http').Server(app);
//var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
console.log(window.location)
console.log(window.location.href)
var matched = false;
var rps = {
    checker: 0
}
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // nbroom
    res.sendFile("public/index.html");    
}); 
let server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("En écoute sur http://127.0.0.1:"+port);
});
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server).sockets;

// var connections = 0;
var start = 0;
var partialBoards = {}
var boards = {};
var matchmakingboard = null;

let nbroom = 0;
```

The error i am getting on the website is 'Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server.'
When i go on the terminal then doing node server after entering the virtual environnement im getting error: could not find mondule server.js

Comment: I was getting many errors on my cpanel server, then i switched to linux/ngnix based server

Comment: Did you try with ```npm install --save express```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save your modules in dependencies.

```
npm install --save module_name
```